# Replace file as data source with vector in c++

Tags: c++

I have this c++ code but the data source is a file.
I want to replace the source with a vector and get the data from a vector.

This is the code:

```
    bool Initialize_Graph(Graph *graph)
{
    
    ifstream file;
    file.open(INPUT_FILE_PATH);
    
    string from , to;
    double rate;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CURRENCIES; i++)
    {
        
        for(int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_CURRENCIES; j++)
        {
            
            file>>from;
            file>>to;
            file>>rate;
            
            if(i == 0)
                graph[j].name = to;
            
            if(i == j)
                Edge_length(graph, i, j, 0);
            
            else
                Edge_length(graph, i, j, -log(rate));
            
        }
        
    }
    
    file.close();
    
    return true;
    
}
```

Instead of "file.open(INPUT_FILE_PATH);" I want to use a vector as data source.

How can I do this and instead of:

```
file>>from;
file>>to;
file>>rate;
```

Use a

> vector<string, string, double> myData;

To can do something like this:

```
myData>>from
myData>>to
myData>>rate
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a `vector<string, string, double>`. Even if you had a `vector<CustomDataType>`, there's no way you could do `myData >> from;` etc because vectors don't support that operation. Your question is unclear to me.

Comment: `bool Initialize_Graph(Graph *graph)` -- Maybe you should redesign your code so that initialization doesn't care where the data is coming from.  It shouldn't have had any I/O to begin with, to be honest with you.

Comment: What you are asking for is impossible (for at least a couple of reasons). If you explain **why** you want to do this then maybe someone could tell you the closest practical option. If you just want to get your data from a vector and don't really care too much about the details then of course that is possible.

Comment: Is `Graph` a class?  If so, how do you construct one with data?  And if `Graph` is a class, why is there a free function called `Initialize_Graph` to do this?  Wouldn't the Graph constructor or similar `public` member function of `Graph` take data in some way, and then initialize the `Graph` object?

Comment: Question is badly stated. If this is some online problem, please post link to this problem so it is clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Have you tried reading how file I/O and vectors work? If you've read about it in a bit detailed way, i think you'd probably dont even ask this question. because, for one, vectors arent supposed to be made like that . They're supposed to be ```vector<Datatype>``` or ```vector<CustomDatatype>``` and not ```vector<datatype1,datatype2,datatype3...>``` 
and for 2, you've not shown enough requirements for the question to even be valid in the first place. what is ```graph``` here? a class ? an array? or a pointer to something? you didnt even show what other custom functions do?

Comment: atleast you couldve put some comments that "it does this "or "it does that" if youre not putting what those custom functions do.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example implementation of reading it from a `std::vector`. But you have to either create the vector in a static way as I show in the example, or load elements dynamically, depending on your use case.

```
bool Initialize_Graph(Graph* graph) {

// Example vector to hold the data 'from', 'to', and 'rate'
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> data = {
    { "USD", "EUR", "0.9" },
    { "EUR", "INR", "89.5" }
};

auto it = data.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CURRENCIES; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_CURRENCIES; ++j) {
        std::string from = (*it)[0];  // access the first string from the vector element
        std::string to = (*it)[1];    // access the second string from the vector element
        double rate = std::stod((*it)[2]);

        if (i == 0)
            graph[j].name = to;

        if (i == j)
            Edge_length(graph, i, j, 0);
        else
            Edge_length(graph, i, j, -std::log(rate));

        ++it;    // increment the iterator to get to the next vector element 
    }
}

return true;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can change it so you can use a file or vector.

**BUT** there are a couple of steps.

#### Step 1: Read records as an atomic object.

Rather than reading all the parts of a record one by one. Create an object and read them all as one object.

This then allows you to iterate the stream or a vector as if they were a single object.

```
struct Record
{
    std::string from;
    std::string to;
    double      rate;
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str, Record& data)
{
    return str >> data.from >> data.to >> data.rate;
}
```

### Step 2: Have a vector of Records

```
std::vector<Record>   data;
// Put the data into the vector
// I will look at this again in step 5.
```

### Step 3: Change the function to use iterator

You want to change the `Initialize_Graph()` function so you pass an iterator. That way you can pass an iterator to a vector or an iterator to a stream and make it work exactly the same.

```
template<typename I>
bool Initialize_Graph(I begin, I end, Graph *graph)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CURRENCIES; i++)
    {          
        for(int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_CURRENCIES; j++)
        {                
            Record  r= *begin;   // Get the record from the iterator.
            ++begin;             // rather than reading from/to/rate from
                                 // a stream.

            if(i == 0) {
                graph[j].name = r.to;
            }
            
            if(i == j) {
                Edge_length(graph, i, j, 0);
            }
            else {
                Edge_length(graph, i, j, -log(r.rate));
            }
        }
    }
    return true;        
}
```

### Step 4: Call using vector.

Using a vector:

Using a file:

```
std::ifstream file(INPUT_FILE_PATH);
Initialize_Graph(std::istream_iterator<Record>{file},
                 std::istream_iterator<Record>{},
                 graph);
```

// Using a vector:

```
std::vector<Record>  data;
// read the data into the vector above. (See Step 5)

Initialize_Graph(std::begin(data),
                 std::end(data),
                 graph);
```

### Step 5: (optional)

You can read the data directly from the file into the vector if you want.

```
std::ifstream file(INPUT_FILE_PATH);
std::vector<Record>  data(std::istream_iterator<Record>{file},
                          std::istream_iterator<Record>{});
```

Comment: I get `use of udeclared identifier "from", "to" and "rate"`

Comment: @Udbdjfj Opps. Fixed. Forgot to add the object in the stream reader.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments said, it's not entirely clear what your code does, `std::vector<std::string, std::string, double>` does not exist, and `std::vector` does not support stream operations like `>>`.

Here's an alternative:

You could store each exchange rate as a tuple consisting of two string's (the from and to currencies) and a single double (the actual conversion rate). Then `std::vector` can be used to store a list of these exchange rates and structured bindings can be used to easily access the tuple elements.

```cpp
// Define a new type to encapsulate an exchange rate:
// a tuple of two strings (from and to currencies) and a double (the actual rate).
typedef std::tuple<std::string, std::string, double> ExchangeRate;

// Store a list of exchange rates.
std::vector<ExchangeRate> exchange_rates = {
    {"USD", "GBP", 2.04},
    {"GBP", "EUR", 1.03},
};

// A structured binding can be used to easily access the tuple elements.
const auto [from_currency, to_currency, rate] = exchange_rates[0];
```